# React native navigator, this.props.navigator.pop not calling constructor() & ComponentDidMount()

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, velo

My questions details is as describe in [Github library  issues.](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2152)

I'm working on Wix Navigation which is also called React Native Navigation. in this library, when i pop the navigation to recent screen then it's not calling neither constructor() not ComponentDidMount().

Is there anyone, who used this concept and had same issue??

Please help me..

Comment: ProTip: Offsite links are better as plain URLs to give people a clue as to where you want them to go. Also, I clicked through to that Git link, and the original issue is short enough that it would be better for you to just copy-and-paste it here. Also, both GitHub and this site allow backtick to indicate `code format` for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the expected behavior that if a screen is popped from the stack and the previous screen showed. When you add a screen to stack with push you just add a screen on top of the current screen and it is not unmounted. So when you go back it is not re-rendered.